# Kendo - Validation Tooltip Location

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm working with Kendo-UI, and am having some issues with the Validations tooltips.
Currently, they work as required, and are showing up at each field.

However, I want a little bit of a customized validation.

Does anyone know of a way to attach/append these validations to my own div instead of the field they are validating.

My goal is to create a list of validation errors at the top of the page.

Thanks,

Comment: have you tried using the @Html.ValidationSummary() control? If you can provide a code sample that would help to answer your question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this for customising the validation tooltip?

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/framework/validator/overview#customizing-the-tooltip-position